# XGBoost extract training predictions

Tags: r, xgboost

In producing a model on a very noisy dataset I need to extract the predictions made by the final XGBoost model on the training set. I know I can extract out-of-fold predictions from xgb.cv but I then cannot use that to predict on the held-out test set.

I appreciate that this is not a usual use-case but it is necessary so find which samples represent outliers in the training set for further exploration and later model stacking.

Is there a way to show the predictions made on the training set by the final model? I would have thought since I can get an error at each round I could but I cannot find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having thought a bit more, it would appear that what I am looking for is an analog to Random Forest's out-of-bag predictions. However, due to the nature of boosted trees there isn't really a "true" OOB sample because any sample may have appeared in previous trees.

I think the closest approach would to be to take the predictions from a CV XGB model using the same parameters and random seeds as the trained model.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstood the question, but wouldn't `predict()` work?

```
model = xgboost(data = data$train, nround = 20,param=param)
training_predictions = predict(model, data$train)
```

Also, I'm on a machine where I can't install XGB, but I'm pretty sure the model object has the final predictions as one of the elements.

Comment: Running predict on the training set results in 100% accuracy, similar to Random Forests because the trees have seen all of the data during training.

The final model object also doesn't have the final predictions (or at least I cannot for the life of me find it) which is odd as it can still calculate the error on the training set.